# Remove wireless connections

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, microsoft-surface

After upgrade to Win8.1 I can no longer manage the wireless profiles nor connect to some of the more complex connections I once had.

I have several serious problems:

- `netsh wlan show profiles` - does not show all the profiles listed in the wireless connection dialog.
- one of the missing profiles is the domain secure login. (I have tried as domain login in admin group and as local admin to list and delete these profiles).
- the right click 'forget' was removed so that isn't available.
- I have other profiles showing up in the wireless dialog with Autoconnect enabled that I cannot reset (comes back after another login). One is ominously labeled HIDDEN.

Seems I may have been hacked or 8.1 isn't ready for prime time.

Does anyone know of some System Internals like tools that are available to cover up the 8.1 shortcomings re wireless management?

Is there a reset I can do short of melting down the Surface Pro?

Comment: FYI I have much higher rep on other stack sites but stack exchange refuses to accept my proper login authentication so I just created a login in the only one this exchange will accept.

Comment: You could try something like http://www.thewindowsclub.com/wifi-profile-manager-windows-8 It seems like it's a GUI for dealing with wireless profiles.  However, it might only run the netsh command in the background and run a pretty UI to view it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in windows 8.1. Try reverting the old manufacturer's drivers instead of the drivers that win 8.1 is trying to use. I found a step by step guide on how to do that: http://www.virusresearch.org/no-internet-access-in-windows-8-limited-connectivity/